# How to speed up the SELECT query from AS/400 (IBM iSeries) - VB. NET Programming

Tags: database, vb.net, ibm-midrange

I am not a programmer, I just need very basic query to get the information from the same table (so only SELECT statement is needed to use in my program).

I try
`SELECT INFOR.PFAC , INFOR.PPAR FROM   MAINSYSTEM.INFOR INFOR WHERE ppar = '240XXX2A'`

but it takes like 3 mins to return the value while when I use the Data Transfer from iSeries, the speed is so quick. Is there any way I can speed up the query?

I use `Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)}` to connect.

I have a button when I press then button, it will get the data and display to a gridView

```
    Dim MyODBCConnection As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};" & _
    "System=163.201.28.55 ;Default Collection=bpcshv81.PEXPLOSNA;")

    'Open the connection
    MyODBCConnection.Open()
    Dim Table_BOM As New DataTable
    Dim Table_BOM_Fill As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT PEXPLOSNA.PFAC , PEXPLOSNA.PPAR FROM    MAINSYSTEM.INFOR  PEXPLOSNA WHERE ppar = '240XXX2A'", MyODBCConnection)

    Table_BOM_Fill.Fill(Table_BOM)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table_BOM
```

Comment: What VB code are you using to retrieve the data?

Comment: I just have a button when I press it, it will load the data to a gridView

Comment: Is it actually 3 minutes every time?

Comment: When you use Data Transfer, are you specifying the selection criteria on ppar?

Comment: Are you trying to display a full hierarchical bill of materials?  If so you will likely need a more complex type of query called a recursive or hierarchical query.  But let's solve this question first, eh? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the delay may be opening the connection.

Perhaps you can try opening it first, getting your overhead out of the way, before you even display the button.

Of course this may mean you would want to move where you close the connection too.  You want to open the connection once, and close it only once when you are done.

You may want to use the .NET Data Provider supplied with iSeries Access.

Check that you are using the latest available version of iSeries Access, and *make sure* it has the patch installed.  Your iSeries Access version can be newer than the system's OS release, but you don't want it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the IBM DB administrator to build an index for you.

Comment: He gets fast response for the same thing if he uses file transfer.